# Dual cone and sum of closed cones

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, dual-cone

Picture below is from the 35 page of  *Schneider R.-Convex Bodies_ The Brunn-Minkowski Theory-Cambridge University Press (2013)* , I think $C^o$ is always closed no matter $C$ is closed or not. Because the inner product is continuous.  Besides the  I think the sum of closed convex cones must be closed, because the sum is continuous . Where is my mistake ?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $C^\circ$ is always closed.

However, the sum of the closed convex cones
$$A = (-\infty,0] \times \{(0,0)\} \\ B = \operatorname{cl-cone}(B_{1}(1,1,0))$$
is not closed. Here, $B_{1}(1,1,0))$ is the closed ball centered at $(1,1,0)$ with radius $1$, touching all three coordinate planes.

Comment: Why the closed ball $B_{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$ is convex cone ?

Comment: No, this is not a cone. But $B$ is defined as the conic hull of $B_{1}(1,1,1)$. Oh, there was a mistake, the radius should be $1$ instead of $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: And the midpoint should be $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: why the sum is not closed ?  I can't see it .

Comment: Because its intersection with the xz-plane is only the x-axis, but the closure contains the xz-plane.

Answer (score -1):

I just think the answer of gerw is a little complex. So I according his way make the below picture . Green and Black are two closed cones , but the sum of them is open ( the sum is $R^2$).

> [image]